# recursive type initialization in julia

Tags: types, julia

I have a problem with those two structs I defined:

```
mutable struct QMDDnode{T}
  next::QMDDnode{T}
  ref::Int
  v::Int
  renormFactor::Int
  ident::Bool
  diag::Bool
  block::Bool
  symm::Bool
  c01::Bool
  computeSpecialMatricesFlag::Bool
  e::Array{T} # type QMDDedge
  QMDDnode()=(x=new();x.next=x;x.e=Array{QMDDedge,1}(4);x)
end

mutable struct QMDDedge
  p::QMDDnode{QMDDedge}
  w::Complex
  sentinel::Int
  QMDDedge()=(x=new();x.p=QMDDnode{QMDDedge}();x)
end
```

I'm trying to understand how to properly initialize them, writing the correct constructors.
If I call

```
b = QMDDedge()
```

I have a quite well defined object "b", but the elements of array e[] are #undef.

Is there a proper way to initialize them?

thanks,
Fausto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Incomplete Initialization](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/constructors#Incomplete-Initialization-1) in the docs. (maybe [LightGraphs.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/LightGraphs.jl) is what your looking for)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it has been very useful!